# Batch Update With API Using Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to update multiple records at the same time which requires me to have an array of id's being sent with my form data. I am using Vue.js and sending the data from my vuex store via axios.

The data is being sent from my vue component like so:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateCheckedEngagements']),
    updateChecked() {
      this.updateCheckedEngagements({
        engagements: this.checkedEngagements,
        assigned_to: this.engagement.assigned_to,
        status: this.engagement.status
      }) 
    },
}
```

The `this.checkedEngagements` is collecting the array of id's I will be updating. However, since I am using vuex to actually send the data, I am doing the following and it hasn't been something I have needed to do previously, so I am trying to get clarity on if this is the correct way. Here is the method in my vuex store

```
updateCheckedEngagements(context, engagement, checkedEngagements) {
      axios.patch('/engagementsarray', {
        engagements: checkedEngagements,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
      })
      .then(response => {
          context.commit('updateCheckedEngagements', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data)
      })           
    },
```

Now the issue is passing the the 3rd parameter in the method right here:

```
updateCheckedEngagements(context, engagement, checkedEngagements)
```

I am not sure it is actually sending the array of id's. I do know that the id's are being collected from the form when I do a `console.log(this.checkedEngagements)`. however, I feel as though I am missing something when I send it to vuex... any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Vuex actions and mutations only accept two arguments. If you want to pass multiple parameters, you need to pass an object as the second parameter, where each property is one of the parameters you want to pass.

Comment: Yeah if I place the `checkedEngagements: []` inside of the `engagement` object but when I do that the `v-model` where I am capturing the array of Id's is not populating which seems to be a separate issue regarding nested arrays.. and vice versa if i don't define the 'checkedEngagements` when I use the action it will return the alarm `checkedEngagements` is not defined...

Comment: I put together a little example to make sure I understand. I left some comments in there describing how I think it should work. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WaYbdY?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert, thank you for taking the time, however I changed `updateCheckedEngagements(context, engagement, checkedEngagements)` to `updateCheckedEngagements(context, checkedEngagements)`, and updated my `v-model` to be more explicit. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So I came to this solution.

```
...mapActions(['updateCheckedEngagements']),
    updateChecked() {
      this.updateCheckedEngagements({
        engagements: this.checkedEngagements.engagements,
        assigned_to: this.checkedEngagements.assigned_to,
        status: this.checkedEngagements.status
      }) 
    },
```

My store is like this

```
updateCheckedEngagements(context, checkedEnagements) {  
      axios.patch('/engagementsarray', {
        engagements: checkedEnagements.engagements,
        assigned_to: checkedEnagements.assigned_to,
        status: checkedEnagements.status
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          context.commit('updateCheckedEngagements', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data)
      })           
    },
```

I was having issue trying to collect array of id's and using same object to send data with. This was because I was not being explicit enough with my naming. When I would nest the `checkedEngagements:[]` array in my `engagement` object it would reference the `v-for` I was looping through instead of the object. To see what I am talking about I will post the `v-for` loop

```
<tbody>
              <tr v-for="(engagement, index) in engagementFilter" :key="index">
                <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" :value="engagement.id" v-model="checkedEngagements.engagements"></th>
                <th>{{ engagement.client.last_name}}, {{ engagement.client.first_name}} & {{ engagement.client.spouse_first_name}}</th>
                <td>{{ engagement.status }}</td>
                <td>{{ engagement.assigned_to }}</td>
                <td>{{ engagement.return_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ engagement.year }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

So because the `v-for` was using `engagement` I could not also use `engagement` in my `v-model`. Instead of using `v-model="enagagement.checkedEngagements"` I used `v-model="checkedEngagements.engagements"`